# Why would VirtualBox abort and take Ubuntu down with it

Tags: virtualbox, ppa, crash, cairo-dock

I am running VirtualBox on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS had Windows 10 running in a guest machine, I had no problems with either Ubuntu or VirtualBox, I was also using Cairo dock and had no problems with that either, until today when VirtualBox crashed without warning, I could see that the guest machine which as running Windows 10 Pro 64b, was aborted and while I was trying to figure out what went wrong by looking in the VirtualBox logs, Ubuntu crashed.

When I restarted Ubuntu, the crash log reads:

```
-rw-r-----  1 me  whoopsie  2060878 Sep 17 17:41 _usr_bin_nautilus.1000.crash  
-rw-r-----  1 root whoopsie 91135782 Sep 17 15:38 _usr_lib_virtualbox_VirtualBoxVM.0.crash
```

Also cairo-dock failed to load and not only did it fail to load, there is actually no trace of it on my system and when I listed all installed apps in the terminal with the following commands, there is no cairo dock in the results, so it appears to have disappeared, its as if it was never on my system I cant find any trace of it:

```
apt list --installed |grep cairo  
dpkg --get-selections | awk '{print $1}' |grep cairo
```

Any ideas as to what could cause the crashes VirtualBox followed by Ubuntu and then cause an installed application to completely disappear off my Ubuntu system, apart from maybe a magician?

Comment: The reason for the crash is probably in those .crash files. They tend to be pretty comprehensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I never got to the bottom of these issues, I resolved them all by doing the following:

1. cairo-dock - Reinstalled with the latest version (3.4.1-1.2)
2. VirtualBox - Upgraded to Version 6.0.12 r133076 (Qt5.9.5)
3. Nautilus - The Linux OS Kernel has been upgraded several times and Nautilus has not crashed since.  I went from Kernel version `4.18.0-22.23~18.04.1` through to the current kernel version:

   ```
   Linux version 5.0.0-31-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-046) (gcc version
   7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)) #33~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 10:20:39 UTC 2019
   ```

So I can only conclude that the problems I was having were all unrelated and merely coincidental and that each of these app versions were unstable and after upgrading them I had no more problems and the issues with Nautilus were taken care of in one or the several kernel updates and I have had no problems since :)